# Ping and use three octet ipv4 addresses. Why is it working?

Tags: linux, debian, ip-address, ipv4

By accident I had a typo and discovered that I can ping and ssh to IP address `10.8.290` ... right one octet is missing. Can someone explain it to me? Is this part of the protocol or some linux-black-magic (I am using Debian)?

```
user@ws:~$ ping -c3 10.8.290
PING 10.8.290 (10.8.1.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.1.34: icmp_req=1 ttl=62 time=0.910 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.1.34: icmp_req=2 ttl=62 time=0.686 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.1.34: icmp_req=3 ttl=62 time=0.708 ms

--- 10.8.290 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.686/0.768/0.910/0.100 ms
user@ws:~$ ssh root@10.8.290
The authenticity of host '10.8.290 (10.8.1.34)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 21:bd:7e:fb:1e:6d:1e:c1:e9:11:c0:a9:73:a8:cf:85.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because you are using a value of `290` for the third byte of the ip address. A byte can store values from `0` to `255`, giving `256` values. Since an IPv4 address is a 4 byte value passing `290` to the third byte leads to an integer overflow into the 4th byte -> `290` - `256` => `34`

It has nothing to do with a *protocol "feature"*. `ping` simply don't validate the values of the individual octets of the `target` command line argument and simply passes it to the lower level C function `inet_aton()` (aton means ascii to number). This results in pinging `10.8.1.34`.

I'm not sure, but I expect other versions of ping (on Windows, BSD) behaving the same.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. I just tested it with windows; Same result!

Comment: You are welcome. I had a look at the source code of the BSD version of `ping`. Also same result..